# forcehybrid command returns npm is required but could not be found

Tags: node.js, npm, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I am doing a POC for implementing Salesforce Hybrid App. I am working on Windows Server2012R2. I installed the Node js required for it. But, when i run the 'npm' command it throws 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.' However, alternatively i was able to run the command 'npm.cmd' successfully.

Q1) Why the actual npm command does not work?

I was able to install forcehybrid package, but when i try to run the command 'forcehybrid.cmd create', it throws me the following message:"'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
Missing tools npm is required but could not be found. Please install npm."

Q2) Why is it throwing above message even though npm is installed?

I have set the path correctly for npm. Below is my path

User Variable Path: C:\Users(Username)\AppData\Roaming\npm

System Variable Path: C:\Program Files\nodejs

Can someone please advise what is it that i am following wrong?